# How to make text box first value non editable in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make a text box field for coutry code generate. So I need to put first letter as a "+" symbol only. And then make it not editable field for that symbol.

```
_handlePhoneNumber(e) {
    var curState = {};
    var valueLength = e.target.value.length;
    var currentValue = e.target.value;
    console.log(currentValue);  

    curState[e.target.name] = this.mobileOnly(currentValue);
    this.setState(curState);
}

<input type="tel" name="countryCode" value={this.state.countryCode} onChange={this._handlePhoneNumber.bind(this)} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the initial value of `this.state.countryCode` as `+`:

```
this.state = {
   countryCode: '+'
}
```

Inside `onChange` function check the length of value entered by user and if **length == 0** then do not update the state value. By this way user will not be able to remove the `+` sign, because we are not updating the state when length is equals to 0.

Like this:

```
_handlePhoneNumber(e) {
    if(e.target.value.length > 0){        //then only update the state value

        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: this.mobileOnly(e.target.value)
        });

    }
}
```

**Note:** `e.target.value` will always contain `+` as first character so before applying any validation or doing calculation remove `+` first.

**Suggestion:**

You can use [MaskedInput Lib](https://github.com/insin/react-maskedinput) also, it provides all these features.

Check this **working Snippet**:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
   constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {
         value: '+'
      }
      this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);
   }
   
   _onChange(e){
      let val = e.target.value;
      if(val.length > 0 && this._isNumeric(val)){
          this.setState({
              [e.target.name]: val
          })
      }else if(val.length == 1){
          this.setState({
              [e.target.name]: '+'
          })
      }
   } 
   
   _isNumeric(val){
       return /^\d+$/.test(val.substr(1));
   }
   
   
   render(){
      return(
         <div>
            <input name='value' value={this.state.value} onChange={this._onChange}/>
         </div>
      )
   }   
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('container'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'/>
```

Comment: e.target.value.length

Comment: mobileOnly(str) {
  return extract(str, '[+0-9]+');
 }

Comment: DO you know how make first letter plus symbol?

Comment: define the initial value of state variable as `+` like this `countryCode: '+'`.

Comment: I mean, after enter "+" symbol then restrict enter plus symbol!

Comment: @vijayaganth check the working snippet in updated answer, this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple input fields like that i suggest you jQuery mask api which does same as code from answer above. Here's link : https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/